# Doctrine migration on Symfony for updating tables in multiple Schemas

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine, symfony4, doctrine-migrations

We are migrating our Software from our own and legacy PHP framework to Symfony.
Our application has different Schema for every user. So beside public Schema, we have about 2.000 user Schemas.
Let's say that we have a system similar to the marketplace, and every user can customize some tables inside their own Schema, but let's not focus on that.

We are currently searching for the best solutions for two problems:

1. When a new user is registered, our Symfony should run migrations only for that newly created user Schema.
2. When we create migration we need that that migration affects ALL existing user Schemas.

Currently, in our old system, we do these kinds of migration with a bunch of PHP logic, and I would like to avoid customizing DoctrineMigrationsBundle or have hundreds of lines of PHP code in a single migration.

**So I would like to know is there any easier way to handle all user Schemas in Doctrine/Symfony, so when I run for example:**

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

**all our existing user Schemas are updated.**

---

Our user Schema names are like `app234234`, `app453453` and except those Schemas we have only default `public` Schema

We are using:

- Symfony 4.3
- PostgreSQL 9.1
- PHP 7.3

Answer (score 2):

1 - For every schema you have, you can define a schema filter. Let's say you prefix user table with schema name  **app234234_** . To prevent migrations from removing your other tables, you can use doctrine dbal **schema_filter** property in your config.yml/doctrine.yml or wherever you define new users's schema

```
## doctrine.yml

    doctrine:
        dbal:
            connections:
                 app234234:
                       schema_filter: "/^app234234_/" ## more likely a %schema_name% parameter
```

**According to symfony doc**: This ignores the tables on the DBAL level and they will be ignored by the diff command.

Note that if you have multiple connections configured then the schema_filter configuration will need to be placed per-connection

2- Regarding your second point, i don't know if this is something you can/should handle with symfony.